# Test for convergence: $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty n^p(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

> Test for convergence:
>   $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty n^p(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})$$
>   where $p\in\mathbb{R}$

**My attempt:**
Case 1: $p\ge0$
$\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$
$n\ge1\Rightarrow n^p\ge1\Rightarrow n^p(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})\ge(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})$
$\therefore\underset{n=1}{\overset{\infty}{\sum}}n^p(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})\ge\overset{\infty}{\underset{n=1}{\sum}}(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})\ge0$
We know that $\overset{\infty}{\underset{n=1}{\sum}}(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})$ diverges
$\Rightarrow\underset{n=1}{\overset{\infty}{\sum}}n^p(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})$ also diverges.

> I don't know how to proceed when $p<0$.

Comment: $\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n\sim1/(2\sqrt n)$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown For $p<0$ we get $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}0\le n^p\le1\Rightarrow 0\le n^p(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})\le \frac{n^p}{2\sqrt{n}}$ and finally, we get that it should converge for all $p<\frac{-1}{2}$. I think I am wrong..? What about $\frac{1}{2}\le p<0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following fact:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^p}<\infty \text{ if } p> 1 $$
For $p<0$, 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2n^{1/2}n^{-p}}<\infty, \text{ if   } \frac{1}{2}-p>1$$
and 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2n^{1/2}n^{-p}}=\infty, \text{ if   } \frac{1}{2}-p\leq 1$$